# Setting a class property as a function - will the function get called when an instance of the class is made?

Tags: javascript, class, function

If I write this:

```
function thing() {
    this.timer = Date.now();
}
```

Will `Date.now()` return the time that I make an instance of the class each time I make one, or just keep returning the time that the script was loaded?

Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a constructor is executed *each time* you invoke it. Just like any other function. Since the body of your constructor calls `Date.now`, it will be called every time.

If it wasn't executed every time, every instance would share all the same properties... which would kind of defeat the point of it!

However, you may have been thinking about `thing.prototype`. If you set `timer` as a property of that, it would *not* be evaluated for each instantiation, and every instance would share the same property (and therefore the same value):

```
thing.prototype.timer = Date.now(); // Not what you want!
```

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/MUsP2/1/). Notice how the first 2 times are different, and the second 2 times are the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it will return the time that you make an instance,

```
function thing() {
    this.timer = Date.now();
    console.log(this.timer)
}
```

//Both of this will log different times.

```
new thing();
new thing()
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.timer` will always return the value of the time at which `thing` was instantiated. It will be set once for that instance when `new thing()` is called and will always return this value unless explicitly reset.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/QrUWR/1/

```
function thing() 
{
    this.timer = Date.now();
}

var o1 = new thing();
alert(o1.timer);
alert(o1.timer);

var o2 = new thing();
alert(o2.timer);
alert(o1.timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.4):

> The `now` function return a Number value that is the time value designating the UTC date and time of the occurrence of the call to `now`.

So,

> Will `Date.now()` return the time that I make an instance of the class each time I make one

Yes.